# How to tell GWT not to compile browser-specific permutations of GWT core and JDK emulation?

Tags: gwt

I have some code that used to compile with GWT 1.x and link into a single script. Now with GWT 2.0.x (GWT 2.0.3 specifically), the compiler compiles 6 browser-specific permutations and then the single-script linker refuses to link.

I don't use GWT widgets. I only use com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer, com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject/EntryPoint/JavaScriptException from GWT core and java.lang and java.util emulation.

How do I tell GWT to compile the core stuff without browser-specific permutations?

Comment: If you are *only* using `Timer` and JSO (which means you are using JS) then why bother with GWT at all? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm using GWT, because I have an existing Java codebase that I want to compile into JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm... you can set in `.gwt.xml` to compile your module only for one browser. gwt.core is not your module, but maybe if you set module that is using it to only one browser it compiles modules that it need also only for this one browser?

To tell GWT to compile module for one browser, set in your `.gwt.xml` e.g. for firefox:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"></set-property>
```